# display selected datagridview item to textbox on another form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing a pos system that require user to select product from list which is located on another form, the list is generated in datagridview. what I need now is when I click on the item on the datagridview list it should display in textbox on the pos form. I have the below code but it does not pass value to the form

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    POS pos = new POS();
    pos.txtProductCode.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    pos.txtProductName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    this.Hide();
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not passing anything in the code youve posted

Comment: so how do i pass it?

Comment: you are creating a new instance of 'POS' form here. is that what you want? to show a new instance of form every time user click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If POS is your form, you should show it.

Change 'this.Hide();' to 'POS.Show()'

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    POS pos = new POS();
    pos.txtProductCode.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    pos.txtProductName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    pos.Show();
}
```

It should work!

**Edit:**

Also, if your POS form has been visible already and form with dataGridView was opened from it, so you should use reference to owner form.

POS form:

```
private void buttonOpenProductList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var productListForm = new ProductListForm(); // It is form with DataGridView
    productListForm.Show(this); // Set owner form
}
```

ProductList form (your form with DataGridView):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    POS pos = (POS)this.Owner;
    pos.txtProductCode.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    pos.txtProductName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    this.Close();
}
```

**Example with ctor:**

POS form:

```
private void buttonOpenProductList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var productListForm = new ProductListForm(this); // It is form with DataGridView
    productListForm.Show();
}
```

ProductList form (your form with DataGridView):

```
private POS pos;
// Constructor of ProductListForm
public ProductListForm(POS pos)
{
    this.pos = pos;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    pos.txtProductCode.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    pos.txtProductName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: i tried this it throws in an exception (An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Store Management System.exe)

Comment: @UmarE.Shaibu 
Show your stacktrace and full exception message.
What is problem line? This "POS pos = (POS)this.Owner;" or another?

Comment: POS pos = (POS)this.Owner; that is where the exception is thrown

Comment: Check place where you open child form with DataGridView. 
You should put owner as parameter of  'Show' method, it is necessarily!

Look my code: productListForm.Show(this); // Set owner form

Comment: i did that see the code 'private void btnSlect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var frmProductList = new frmProductList(); // It is form with DataGridView
            frmProductList.Show(this); // Set owner form
        }'

Comment: Here example for you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz31i6ombevsq8f/UmarProto.zip?dl=0

Comment: Another way, you can pass the POS form through constructor to child form.
Look here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2irbuwywlqy12ry/UmarProtoWithCtor.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the form you are posting to eg:

```
Form f2 = new Form();

f2.TextBox1.Text = somevalue;
```

Now you will have access to the controls such as TextBox etc on the form you are posting too. You can assign the values to them.

Please note this guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    POS pos = new POS();
    pos.txtProductCode.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    pos.txtProductName.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    pos.Show();
}
```

make textboxes are public

Other wise add a method to fill data in POS.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    POS POS = null;
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form frm in fc)
    {
        if (frm.GetType().Name.Equals("POS"))
        {
            POS = frm as POS;
        }
    }
    if (POS == null)
    {
        POS = new POS();
    }
    string ProductCode = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string ProductName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    POS.FillTextBoxes(ProductCode, ProductName);
    POS.Show();
}
```

in POS:

```
internal  void FillTextBoxes(string productCode, string productName)
{
     txtProductCode.Text = productCode;
     txtProductName.Text = productName;
}
```

CellContentClick work when click on the text. Better to change it to dataGridView1_CellClick or CellDoubleClick.

Also POS.Show() will create a new form on each click. So apply POS.ShowDialog() if suitable for your situation.

Comment: i tried this it worked but instead of adding the values to the current opened form, it opened a new form with the data. i want it to apply the data to the currently opened POS form. thanks.

Comment: do you try with  POS.ShowDialog() ?

Comment: yes i did. it opened a new POS form.. with the value inside.. i want it to put the value in the already opened POS form.. thanks

Comment: I tried to convert the example you sent to use for datagridview still didnot work..